# How to setup git on server?

Tags: git

According to some tuts :

Server Side:

I login to ssh and visit to my project

```
Directory path : ~/public_html/my_prj 
Host (example):110.100.12.112 
User  (Example):user
```

So i create mkdir project.git

and then 
cd project.git and execute git init --bare

Move to 
Client Side :
Visit a  folder say test Then open git console and do these steps :

```
git init .

git remote add origin user@110.100.12.112/~/public_html/my_prj/project.git

git pull origin master
```

But in git console it shows :

```
$ git pull origin master
fatal: 'user@110.100.12.112/~/public_html/my_prj/project.git' does not a
ppear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

??

Can u Help to configure git in server ?

Comment: Why would you do `git init --bare`?

Comment: @JackManey ...to make a bare git repo?

Comment: I don't think that command does what you think it does. Just do a `git init`.

Comment: @JackManey Using `git init --bare` is correct. A remote repository to be pushed and pulled must be bare.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash where you should have a colon.  A colon is used to separate the host from the path in an [ssh path](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

```
username@host:path

user@110.100.12.112:~/public_html/my_prj/project.git
```

Or you can use an SSH URL.

```
ssh://username@host/path

ssh://user@110.100.12.112/~/public_html/my_prj/project.git
```

You can do what you want in one step with clone.

```
git clone user@110.100.12.112:~/public_html/my_prj/project.git
```

Comment: Thanks --  I need Some Answers ?  Q1. git init --bare create a empty repo . How could i add server files into that project.git that can be pull to local client ?  in Server : ~public/my_prj holds all server files , and project.git is inside in it -- and initially its empty when we create it

Comment: Q2. when i push new files into that repo , it pushes , but i cant see that file in server ,becs i think project.git should be branched with the folder that contains codes -- any suggestion ?

Comment: @user3551950 It'll work better if you ask those as new questions.  Post the links here as a comment so I'll see them.